# How to retrieve the last image from an SDcard in Android?

Tags: java, android, image

How can I retrieve the last image in the SDcard (last one captured)?

Answer (score 3):

To get a handle to the File object representing the root of the SD card's filesystem you can use, [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29).

Listing the files in a directory is relatively straight forward using the [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) object's [listFiles()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29) method.